# Sequence in $l_1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $x_n$ be sequence in $l_1$.

$$\sum \frac{|x_i|^2}{2^i} \leq {(sup|x_i|})^2$$

True or false? I can not show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hölder's Inequality, or simply factoring out the the maximum of the numerators, yields
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{|x_k|^2}{2^k}\le\overbrace{\ \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2^k}\ }^1\sup_{k\ge1}|x_k|^2
$$

Comment: I see that the question was changed.

Answer (score 1):

False, consider $x = (42,0,0,\ldots)$.

Comment: Sorry, i wrote wrong, but i edited

Comment: Then it's true. Estimate every $x_i$ by $\sup|x_i|$.